# Is my MySQL Server (run by php/apache) affected by the Log4j vulnerability?

Tags: vulnerability, apache, mysql, node.js, log4shell

From an article for the new Log4j vulnerability, it reads here:

> A researcher working for Chinese tech firm Alibaba discovered the bug and privately informed the Apache Software Foundation, an all-volunteer corporation that develops and maintains open-source software. It spilled into public view when Minecraft made its disclosure and the researcher posted about it online.

*Source: https://www.npr.org/2021/12/14/1064123144/companies-scramble-to-defend-against-newly-discovered-log4j-digital-flaw*

I am currently using a Node.js server that connects to a MySQL Database hosted by Apache2 (to be specific) and I was wondering if the MySQL Database and the Node.js server are also vulnerable?

(Note that  I do not use Apache for my server, I use Node.js and I only use Apache for the SQL server)

If this is a problem, what can I do about it?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/log4j-zero-day-mitigation-guide/

Comment: Do any of these use Java?

Comment: @MechMK1 I'm pretty sure Apache does, and it is mentioned in the article.

Comment: @ParkingMaster No, you're conflating the Apache Software Foundation with Apache httpd, which is often just called "apache". Apache httpd is written in C.